# Is this OR procedure correct?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define or-l (lambda x
               (if (null? x)
                   #f
                   (if (car x) #t
                       (apply or-l (cdr x))))))

(map (lambda (x) (apply or-l x)) '((#t #t) (#f #t) (#t #f) (#f #f)))
'(#t #t #t #f)
```

It will be used in a function that evaluates Boolean expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What is your actual question? If you're asking whether it runs, please check the [help/on-topic] first. At the least we're going to need more information before we can say anything meaningful about it. What is it supposed to do and what will call this function?

Comment: @Mast I've simplified the question. Please tell me if anything is still unclear and otherwise remove the -1.

Comment: The question is answered now, so I'm not sure the question should be edited now. But for the next time, please keep the previous link (to the [help/on-topic]) and our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) in mind.

Comment: how will the -1 impact this question?

Comment: It won't. Your reputation still rose a net 9 points by asking this question and it isn't scoring low enough to be in danger of anything drastic. It will only impact your account if you keep asking questions where the same thing happens, eventually you'll be temporarily question-banned. Read that help center and [our FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) before asking the next one, don't worry, and feel free to ask for help. If you put in the effort, I'm sure you'll be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### `or-l` Is a Poor Name

---

The OP procedure `or-l` is correct in that it yields correct results for its inputs. This `or-l` short-circuits only in the sense that recursive calls through the provided arguments cease when a true value is encountered; yet, this is not the behavior of [`or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._or%29%29), which is a *special form*. The `or-l` procedure always evaluates *all* of its arguments, where the `or` special form evaluates its arguments sequentially until a true value is encountered.

Consider:

```
scratch.rkt> (or #t (/ 1 0))
#t
scratch.rkt> (or-l #t (/ 1 0))
; /: division by zero
```

Here `or` does not evaluate `(/ 1 0)` because it is a special form which only evaluates forms as needed. But, `or-l` is a *procedure* which always evaluates all of its arguments; `(/ 1 0)` is evaluated before the procedure body is entered, and this evaluation results in an error.

The name `or-l` should be reconsidered. The name suggests that this procedure applies `or` to a list, which it does not; it applies `or` to an unspecified number of arguments. It would be better, perhaps, to call it `or-proc` to emphasize that it behaves similarly to `or`, but that it is a procedure and thus evaluates its arguments.

---

### A Better Way

---

OP has written a somewhat lengthy recursive function which is then applied via `map` and an anonymous function to a list of boolean lists to achieve OP goal:

```
(define or-proc
  (lambda x
    (if (null? x)
        #f
        (if (car x)
            #t
            (apply or-proc (cdr x))))))
```

```
(map (lambda (x) (apply or-proc x)) '((#t #t) (#f #t) (#t #f) (#f #f)))
'(#t #t #t #f)
```

A simpler and cleaner approach would be to take advantage of built-in Racket features such as [`ormap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29). Note that `(ormap identity '(#t #f))` is equivalent to `(or (identity #t) (identity #f))`, i.e. `(or #t #f)`.

With this in mind, here is a better `or-l` procedure which actually takes a list argument:

```
(define (or-l xs)
  (ormap identity xs))
```

This procedure can be used more cleanly with the list-of-lists input provided by OP:

```
scratch.rkt> (map or-l '((#t #t) (#f #t) (#t #f) (#f #f)))
'(#t #t #t #f)
```